# How to get a stack trace in native layer on Android at runtime programatically

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an android project that uses a lot of JNI to interact with native application code for it to work.

Many times it happens that some part of my native application code crashes, stalling the java application. I have introduced signal handler to atleast catch any segmentations or anything of that sort happens in native layer, and accordingly informed the java layer to gracefully and cleanly shutdown the entire application so that the next time it start, it works fine.

Now i have reached a stage where i still have some crashes left in native layer but logcat is not enough now to debug where and why this is happening.

Can anyone help me on how i can capture the stack trace on segmentation/signal handling of native application? The native code is compiled using the Android's NDK toolchain and linked in apk using ant.

I am desperately in need of a way to get to know what is happening in native layer.